# Можно ли быть "приятно обрадованным"?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

Загуглила - и выпала в осадок: сплошная приятная обрадованность...

Как же ж жить?

> Ценители неизменного вот уже несколько тысячелетий вида на «учебник
>   ордерной архитектуры», каковым является Колизей, будут **приятно
>   обрадованы** заведениям по улице Nicola Salvi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя, это от зарапортованности говорят: где-то мельком слышали о **приятном удивлении** или порывшейся ("зарывшейся" - сегодня читал) собаке. С падежом "заведений" - тоже несварение (обрадован "чем," а не "чему").

Answer (score 1):

Помню только: "Все трое были приятно ошеломлены".

Я обрадован кем-чем или кому-чему?!

Может, не "улице Nicola Salvi", а "via Nicola Salvi"? Или как оно там по-ихнему...